# how to implement "office 2016 files menu" like in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, ribbon

I developed (C# WinForm) a very simple ribbon bar menu similar to the one used in Office 2016.

The part I do not know how to get start with is the "File" menu. If you are familiar with Office 2016 you know that when you click on "File" you get a page in which you have a menu on the left side, a column with "places" where to search for files, and the list of MRU files.
I like this page but I do not know how to implement it. I was planning to show a panel that overlaps to the app (maybe adding a fade-in/out effect) but it sounds more like "the poor developer" solution. I would appreciate any piece of info/idea/reference that can help me to understand how to show that "page"...then I can figure out how to populate info on it.

Thank you!
Nicola

Comment: That's more or less how that interface works: a set of Panels shown inside the same Win32 Window (named `OpusApp`). The main difference is that the main app has no standard TitleBar or Buttons, these are all custom controls, used to provide a common *look & feel* no matter where the application is installed (not relying on the local System Theme to render the Window parts). The TileBar you see in File View is a set of custom controls that overlap the TileBar elements you see in the editor view (so, when you see the `File` pane, you have actually 2 fake TitleBars, one over the other).

Comment: The Buttons on the side and the Buttons in the MRU/File Browsing section are all Menus with custom Buttons. The central part is a custom panel (`NetUIScrollViewer`) with custom ScrollBars. You can reproduce all these parts quite easily (except the custom scrollbars, those require some more work, but maybe you don't need custom controls for this).

Comment: so..in other words....If I want to mimic the File pane I need to create a Panel that overlaps to the principle application. DO I understand correctly?

Comment: This is what the the Office interface does. You can build a UserControl and dock it (to Fill) inside the Form. Maybe add an animation that makes the left-most pane (part of the UC) slide in. You probably don't need to also create a fake Caption (Title Bar) and overlap that, too.